# View changes before commiting

Tags: svn

I`m going through some repos at work clearing up some differences I have. Is it possible to see changes before commiting?

E.g on my dev copy running `svn st` shows that `dir/file1.php` and `dir/file2.php` have a status of `M`. Can I see what's different between the local changes copy, and the copy on the repo at the moment as some of these files we're changed a while ago and I want to check nothing going to break when I push the files live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Windows box and using the svn ui , you can use svn diff.

if you are a command line man - use the svn diff

Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: I believe so yes, I found `svn diff -r {VERSIONNUMBER} file1.php`, which seems to do the trick nicely for me.